# Dbeaver hiding "COMMENT ON FUNCTION"

Tags: postgresql, dbeaver

I came across weird DBeaver behavior today. When you add "COMMENT ON FUNCTION" in function in DBeaver and save it, the line become invisible. It's there and it's doing its's job but it's not visible.

Can't see this neither in function source neither in sql console after opening through source. I know it's still there. I'm  working with CMDBuild which requires this type of comment to enable function in dashboard panel.

My DBeaver version is 7.1.3. My co-workers use the same database and use DBeaver and see the line as it should be.

Here is magic line I'm talking about.

```
COMMENT ON FUNCTION public."_function_name_example"("int4") IS 'TYPE: function';
```

Comment: dbeaver is not line based, so "line become invisible" has no obvious meaning. Screenshots are usually frowned upon, but in this case maybe one would be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the same version as your and the same database, then perhaps you should check your DBeaver options against theirs. Or as suggested check with support. The other option is a query (or SQL function) that retrieves the comments.

```
select d.description 
  from pg_description  d 
  join pg_class        c
    on c.oid = d.objoid 
 where c.relname = ':table_name' 
   and c.relkind = 'r';
```

See following for [function example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=50943cde2088a5485d807fe2c9d6f268).